# Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression where the user should enter atleast 200 words in the textarea.. I got it working partially with the below code
**/(\w+\s){200,}/**
Now as per the above code, it will show error if the no of words is less than 200. But it accepts only alphabets. So what i want is that it should accept all characters including . , numbers etc.. How is it possible. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If it were me, I would do it entirely differently as just say

```
 var notLongEnough = "This is a test".split(/\s+/,200).length != 200
```

Comment: +1 for limiting it to 200 array elements maximum, thus optimizing the performance of `split()` on very large strings.

Comment: `split` is buggy with regular expressions in IE. What's the benefit of using it over `match`?

Comment: `split()` isn't that buggy with simple regex delimiters. If you want to include capture groups in your output then there is some non standard behavior between browser implementations of `split()`. But for this is works as expected with any reasonable browser I could test against. The benefit here is that it has to do less work. Rather than matching atleast 200 capturing groups (which continue to match into infinity), it just splits until it reaches 200. It's easier to do the work and, and my opinion, easier to understand: "Give me the first 200 items that are separated by whitespace"

Comment: Just for full disclosure, there is one "bug" and that is the input string is untrimmed so you might get actual words + 2 (with empty start and end items in the array) if the string starts and ends with whitespace. But it will handle multiple spaces between words properly and correctly count the last word.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tested function which uses a modified version of your regex.

```js
// Check if string contains at least 200 words.
function validate200WordCount(text) {
    var re = /^\W*(?:\b\w+\b\W*){200}/;
    if (re.test(text)) {
        return "VALID. Text has at least 200 words.";
    } 
    return "INVALID. Text does not have 200 words.";
}
```

The problem with the original regex is that it requires a space to follow each and every word. But in text, lots of words are NOT followed by spaces, e.g. punctuation. The regex needs to allow for any *non-word characters* that may occur between words. The improved regex above defines a word as: `\b\w+\b` *"One or more word characters between word boundaries"* and then allows any number of non-word characters between each word. A `^` beginning of string anchor was added to improve the regex efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

If you *REALLY* wanted to use a match instead of a split, then I would use

```
"   this is a string that has a bunch of stuff   ".match(/^\s*(\S+\s+){199}\S+/)
```

That should find 199 blocks of non-space characters that are separated by whitespace characters, ending with one or more non-space characters (totaling 200 words). This will short circuit after it finds the 200th word, rather than matching into infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do non-space characters followed by a space character:

```
/(\S+\s){200,}/
```

In general, if a character group shorthand matches a certain set of characters, the capitalized version will match the inverse.

Comment: I want to allow the user to type any characters from the keyboard...I guess the above code will not allow users to do so..When I put spaces it will just fail

Comment: Including spaces it should contain min 200 words